# CPANM path not configured correctly

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, cpanm

After extracting a fresh copy of Strawberry Perl, I get an error in CPANM.

```
C:\portable_perl>cpanm --self-upgrade
You are running cpanm from the path where your current perl won't install execut
ables to.
Because of that, cpanm --self-upgrade won't upgrade the version of cpanm you're
running.

  cpanm path   : C:\portable_perl\perl\bin/cpanm
  Install path : C:\portable_perl\perl\site\bin

It means you either installed cpanm globally with system perl, or use distro pac
kages such
as rpm or apt-get, and you have to use them again to upgrade cpanm.

C:\portable_perl>
```

After installing `App::cpanminus` I get a slightly different error.

```
C:\portable_perl>cpanm --self-upgrade
You are running cpanm from the path where your current perl won't install executables to.
Because of that, cpanm --self-upgrade won't upgrade the version of cpanm you're running.

  cpanm path   : C:\portable_perl\perl\site\bin/cpanm
  Install path : C:\portable_perl\perl\site\bin

It means you either installed cpanm globally with system perl, or use distro packages such
as rpm or apt-get, and you have to use them again to upgrade cpanm.

C:\portable_perl>
```

Is there any way to set the path? Or install CPANM differently? I'm running this on Windows 7 x64 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script does

```
$0 !~ /^$install_base/
```

where `$0` is

```
C:\portable_perl\perl\site\bin/cpanm
```

and `$install_base` is

```
C:\portable_perl\perl\site\bin
```

It's not expecting backslashes. `\po`, `\pe`, `\s` and `\b` all have special meaning in regex patterns. This is a bug in `cpanm`.

Comment: Looks like this was [reported in December](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/issues/477).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I spent all day on Friday trying to find that answer :(

Comment: Of course there's a workaround. There are numerous ways of installing `cpanm`. You've even used one yourself between your two tests. The simplest is probably `cpanm cpanm`.